# How can I align 4 boxes with bootstrap grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align some containers using Bootstrap grid system. The final result should look like the following picture.
[image]

But I'm getting the following result instead.

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

I'm asking this question mostly because If I invert the divs I will get the expected result.

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

It may be helpful to let you know that I'm trying to re-create the image layout from: https://founderspledge.com/

Comment: They used position absolute on their design. I think it is called as masonry. I don't think you can achieve it by float.

Comment: @HermLuna , I noticed that when I reviewed the source code but I couldn't find a css/js file with the position absolute specification.

Comment: I think there's a tutorial in youtube called multi-column layout using javascript. That's all you need.

Comment: You need two create two columns, and in the second column put divide into two rows

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing around with creating that layout and come up with this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="lg col-md-6">
      <div class="sm col-md-6">
        small
      </div>
      <div class="sm col-md-6">
        small
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lg col-md-6">
      large
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="lg col-md-6">
      large
    </div>
    <div class="lg col-md-6">
      <div class="sm col-md-6">
        small
      </div>
      <div class="sm col-md-6">
        small
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Here is a link to an example:

http://codepen.io/minipunch/pen/zKYOxO

Let me know if that helps or if you have questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this layout:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">1</div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">2</div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">3</div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2kdd51kw/

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this,
Here is the codepen.io link : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgKKdd

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 small-box">1</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 small-box">2</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 small-box">3</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 small-box">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 box">big content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening becuase of Bootstrap `float:left`. The simplest way would be to use `pull-right` on the layout (`col-md-6`) containing the larger image on the right.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 pull-right"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/g36R42L3Pc

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="lg col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 small-box">1</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 small-box">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 small-box">3</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 small-box">4</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="lg col-md-6 large-box">Large</div>
    </div>
</div>


<style>
.small-box{
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.large-box{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: adding explanation to your answers will be helpful

Comment: First, you divide the screen into two columns. Then place the small boxes and also the large boxes as appropriate. You need to give the box heights according to the screen size. I have given this in vh.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it in Bootstrap 5:

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="row">
  <div class="img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
        <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```